# Loop is not working in Python. I am a Beginner

Tags: python, for-loop

```
places = ("England", "Britain", "United States Of America")
for place in places:
    print(places)
```

I am getting this result:

```
('England', 'Britain', 'United States Of America')
('England', 'Britain', 'United States Of America')
('England', 'Britain', 'United States Of America')
```

Comment: It's just typo error `print(places)` should be `print(place)` so it print's one place at a time

Comment: Look at what you're `print()`ing

Answer (score 0):

print `place` instead of `places`, like below:

```
places = ("England", "Britain", "United States Of America")
for place in places:
    print(place)
```

You should get:
[image]